# Manage state data in Bot Framework v-4

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I am using Bot builder SDK v-4. I am trying to change the default in-memory storage option to either Cosmos DB or Azure table storage to manage the state data. I imported the latest stable `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure` package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/. It gives, what it seems like some compatibility error, which makes the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFramework` namespace irrelevant in the Startup class.

[image]

Also, in my bot class, the `OnTurn` function's `ITurnContext` parameter shows a conflict.

[image]

I uninstalled the problematic package (`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure`) and tried getting rid of the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Core.Extensions.IStorage` from within the `ConfigureServices` function in my Startup class and create my own customized implementation. But looks like it is mandatory to add the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Core.Extensions.IStorage` type as the middleware in the `ConfigureServices`.
The only option I see is to create an implementation of `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Core.Extensions.IStorage` and add that as the middleware. That seems like a lot to me. Is there any other way to fix this?

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp